# Java program does not check SQLite Constraint?

Tags: java, database, sqlite, constraints

Java program does not check SQLite Constraint?

I have to following table structure and their content

```
create table Parent
(
 ParentID int primary key, 
 ParentName varchar(30)  
)
create table child
(
 ChildID int primary key, 
 ParentID int references Parent, 
 ChildName varchar(30) 
)
insert into Parent values(1,'a');
insert into Parent values(2,'b')
insert into Child values(1,1,'c');
insert into Child values(2,1,'d');
insert into Child values(3,1,'e');
insert into Child values(4,1,'f');
```

---

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.List;

public class LiteConn {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Connection con=null;
        Statement st=null;
        ResultSet rs=null;
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");  
            con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\chaitanya\\Documents\\Demo.db");
            st = con.createStatement();
            int i=st.executeUpdate("delete from Parent where ParentID=1 ");
            System.out.println("i "+i);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } 
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e1)
        {
            System.out.println(e1.getMessage());
        }
        finally {
            con.close();
        }

    }

}
```

**
SQLite IDE does not allow to fire this query but when I try this through Java program, this query execute.
(This delete query trying to delete parent row....)**

Answer (score 0):

You must [enable foreign key support](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_enable).